# Authorization Server policy requires PKCE to be used for this request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth Hazelbase authentication service but when I'm deploying, it says `Authorization Server policy requires PKCE to be used for this request`.

**Note: Hazelbase is also a service like sign in with google.**

**Logs Error Screenshot-**

[image]

**[...nextauth.js] file-**

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

export default NextAuth({

    providers: [

        // hazelbase provider

        {
            id: 'hazelbase',
            name: 'Email',
            type: 'oauth',
            version: '2.0',
            authorizationUrl: 'https://api.hazelbase.com/oidc/auth?response_type=code',
            requestTokenUrl: 'https://api.hazelbase.com/oidc/auth',
            accessTokenUrl: 'https://api.hazelbase.com/oidc/token',
            wellKnown: 'https://api.hazelbase.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration',
            profileUrl: 'https://api.hazelbase.com/oidc/me',
            scope: 'openid profile name email',
            protection: 'pkce',
            clientId: process.env.HAZELBASE_CLIENT_ID,
            params: {
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            },
            profile(profile) {
                return {
                    id: profile.sub,
                    ...profile,
                };
            },
        }

    ]
})
```

Comment: If you need anything please let me know

Comment: Check the request to hazel base server and see if `code_challenge=CODE_CHALLENGE&code_challenge_method=S256` is included. are you using the latest version of next-auth?

Comment: @Yan what do you mean I couldn't understand?

Comment: the GET request that is in your screenshot does it have these query params .. `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method`

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE: Without diagnostic details, we cannot help you. please check your NextAuth.js version and the URL of Hazelbase authorization page.

---

PKCE support for NextAuth.js was add on [v3.2.0](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/releases/tag/v3.2.0), please consider check your package versions and re-try with newer version.

To check if PKCE was configured successfully, check the URL of Hazelbase authorization page if `code_challenge` present.